# After create site collection IE cannot display this web page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection

I have successfull created a webapplication in SharePoint 2010. Now I have some problems with Site Collection. SP2010 created it successfull but i cant display it in IE
I have added it to DNS Entry. But still cant display it, Any suggestion?
TIA

UPdated:
A working solution for me was to put the name of my team site in the host file.

eg. 127.0.0.1 team.contoso.com

Best regards

Comment: Since you have mentioned IE , would be interested to know if you are able to open the site collection in another browser other than IE.

Comment: Hi Moss Partner
I've tried with FireFox but it said - Server not found
I think it is something with my DNS?

Comment: Were you browsing the site from the server or from a client machine?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue today at work and the admin guy said he ran the "Setspn" command in powershell. Here's an example taken from this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/20/configuring-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx) where they use kerberos authentication.

Step 2: Set SPN

SPN is required to map the service/host name to the Application Pool identity.

A.) Install SPN from the following location:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5fd831fd-ab77-46a3-9cfe-ff01d29e5c46&displaylang=en

B.) From cmd prompt, run the following cmd:

```
Setspn.exe –a http/contoso.com contoso\farmadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are facing one of the most commonly encountered issues: using FQDN from local machine - a new security measure in .NET 3.5 SP1 forbids you to do so.

You need to follow either of the 2 steps mentioned here to eliminate that (reboot server after registry update): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861